# TYPO3 - Deactivating cHash in own extension causes error when accessing record

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

If I add noCacheHash="1" to link.action I can deactivate cHash:

```
<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record.uid}" noCacheHash="1">{record.name}</f:link.action>

/?tx_abc_abc[record]=1&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc
```

But when trying to access a record I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
#1509296606: Failed to fetch error page "domain/index.php?id=72", reason: Client error: `GET domain/index.php?id=72` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: <script>window.location.href='domain/access-denied/';</script><noscript>Error 401 - Access Deni (truncated...)

20 TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::pageErrorHandler("domain/index.php?id=72", "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", "Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty)")
```

How can I access the record properly when deactivating cHash?

Comment: What works is adding to typoscript: 

    plugin.tx_yourextension.features.requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0

But is this stable and secure?

Answer (score 0):

This is not cause with `noCacheHash` parameters. I think you set special permission for pageID(43). So, this page is not access for this record.

So, First check this page access permission.